# Изменение линий графика в OxyPlot WPF

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

Мне нужно изменить цвет линий самого `PlotView` (не его `Series`). У меня сам дизайн темных цветов, фон я у `PlotView` сделал тоже темным, а его хочу линии посветлее, но никак не найду где они выставляются, документация очень посредственная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос размыт - не ясно о каких линиях идет речь.

Цвет линий для осей задается соответственно для каждой оси:

```
TextColor="White"
TicklineColor="White"
AxislineColor="White"
MajorGridlineColor="White" 
MinorGridlineColor="White"
```

Скорее всего часть этих свойств вам не нужна, но хотя бы дает ответ на вопрос что можно изменить.